# Magento configurable products with colour swatch

Tags: magento, colors, product

Another Magento issue here.

Lets say I have a product, call it a Jumper, available in 3 different colours.
I need to ensure each colour is visible in the product list view - so that's 3 seperate configurable products.

When I view any of these configurable products, I want a colour swatch to be available to toggle the images, and to also replace the 'Choose your colour' dropdown, when adding to basket.

There is this: http://www.extensionsmall.com/magento-color-swatch.html - which would be great, but isn't compatible with my version - and doesnt generate 3 seperate configurable products.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so how did you solve it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

In the end, I utilised the Cross Sell attribute to select products with alternative colours, after creating a new product attribute - hex - which can be called from the crosssell.phtml document to display the swatch thumbnail.

This way, the other colours also display independently in the product listing.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with displaying configurable product as separate products for each colour. And I must say it was hard to develop custom extension. There is many rewrites and dirty hacks in layered navigation, product collections and other.